# First time creating a character for animation and I'm having issues with hooking/rigging. What should I do next?

Tags: animation, rigging

I need to make a 30s animation due Dec 6th and I still have some issues with this character I've been developing. I have made multiple meshes for secondary body parts, clothes and accessories, how can I hook/anchor them into the base mesh so that everything moves once I begin animating? I don't think it is possible to use the CTRL+J method to some meshes as the hair will disappear, since they are multiple meshes of hair strand particles. [image: my character on the material preview. Only the base mesh(body) is parented to the armature. eyes, eyelids, ears, hair, nails and clothes are disconnected. I want them connected to the armature without having to join meshes]

[image: The group "Jonas.001" is where all of his meshes are located, while the group "cabelo1" is where all of his hair strands are (I made them using the arcane hairstyle tutorial by Lightning Boy Studio)]

Answer (score 0):

What you'll need to do is assign the secondary objects to particular bones:

-select all the hair objects
-ctrl+select the rig
-switch to pose mode
-select the head bone
-ctrl+p to parent
-assign to bone

depending on the secondary object you'll be selecting groups of bones and parenting with auto-weighting. Perhaps needing to manually weight paint.

Answer (score 0):

I did this for posing not for animating but i think you can parent ur clothing mesh to the body mesh and it will normally automatically fill in the weight map top (if you use automatic weights) (object mode> select clothing> shift select ur body> parent it)

Comment: Hi, welcome! Blender Stack Exchange isn't like other forums: we focus on high-quality, thorough answers to questions as opposed to speculation or more generic discussion. You could edit and improve this answer if you tested the solution yourself to make sure it's correct (and remove the 'I think' part of your answer by doing so,) and possibly include a few links or screenshots to further explain the process, for example.